# Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and let $\delta(G) = \min_{v\in V}\deg v$ prove the stmt...

Tags: graph-theory

a) if $\deg u + \deg v \ge n-1$ for every two non adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$, then $G$ is connected.

b)Prove that the bound in (a) is sharp by finding a disconnected graph on $n$ vertices such that
$\deg u + \deg v = n - 2$ for each even positive integer.
n.

I got a) but I am unsure of what it means by "bound in (a) is sharp".

Comment: The number of cats I own is less than or equal to 100, but this bound is not sharp. A better upper bound is 1, which is sharp since I do indeed own a single cat.

Comment: Show that we cannot improve the inequality any more. You can perhaps give an example of a graph for which equality is obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say that a bound is sharp if it cannot be improved further.

**(a)** Suppose that $G$ is disconnected, and let $u$ and $v$ in different connected components. Then, in particular, they are not adjacent. Since $\text{deg}(u) + \text{deg}(v) \ge n - 1 > n - 2$ one of the remaining $n-2$ vertices must be adjacent to both $u$ and $v$. But this is a contradiction!

**(b)** When $n$ is even, let $G_n$ be the disjoint union of two complete graphs on $\frac{n}{2}$ vertices. It's easy to check that this graph satisfies $\text{deg}(u) + \text{deg}(v) = n - 2$ for non adjacent $u$ and $v$, but it's also disconnected.